# C++ compiler error "cannot be thread-local because it has non-POD type”"

Tags: c++, multithreading

This statement:

```
___thread A a;
```

Generates this error:

> cannot be thread-local because it has non-POD type

where A is

```
class A{
       public:
               // function declaration
       private:
               // data members
};
```

I am trying this to compile on Linux, with command ogs includes & ogs mk. 
We have static threads i.e. before our application comes in we aware about the number of threads hence currently the work around is done with declaring the array of A i.e.

```
A a[Number of threads].
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Look at __thread A* a; to get ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `gcc`, thread-local storage only supported for `POD` types, i.e. data-only structures.
You can attempt to extract the data into a separate `struct` and make it thread local (actually, that's probably a good idea in any case because there is no much sense in making methods thread local).

Comment: Note that you can make all the data members `private` and have the methods in a separate `friend` class.

Comment: Thanks icepack. However I do not have access to class A template and hence I could not change class A to struct A. class A is already heavily used and hence I need to avoid as much as possible changes to class A. The other work around we thought is in global header file declare __thread A *a; and in thread init function have a = new  A(). But now we dont want to allocate the memory for class A from heap so in any case we need to make it work the statement __thread A       a;

Comment: @CppDeveloper If you're ok with dynamic allocs/deallocs for your class I don't see any problem with this. Your `a` is actually a `POD`, just like required. Otherwise you'll need to make a change to `A` itself. The cleanest way seems to be the one suggested by @ecatmur.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as dynamic initialization (and destruction) of thread local resources in C++03 (which know nothing about threads, anyway).

In C++11, the `thread_local` storage keyword allows for dynamic initialization at the cost of runtime overhead (basically, equivalent to having a thread local static variable) and might thus be used without types with constructors.

In C++11, again, a `constexpr` constructor might be call for static initialization and should thus be compatible with the `__thread` specifier, provided your compiler implements it.